# How to get unsampled data from Google Analytics API - even for one day?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, sample-data

I'm trying to obtain unsampled data from the Google Analytics API, but for some reason it always comes out sampled. Even if I select only **one day** and **filter for one page only**. This is what I've tried on Google's Query Explorer:

[image: Sampled Data Always]

What do I need to do to overcome this? Also, is there a way to see how much of the data is sampled (without having to log into the Google Analytics page...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your query you need to supply a [sampiling level](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#samplingLevel)

```
samplingLevel=DEFAULT Optional.
  Use this parameter to set the sampling level (i.e. the number of visits used to 
  calculate the result) for a reporting query. The allowed values are consistent with
  the web interface and include: 
       •DEFAULT — Returns response with a sample size that balances speed and accuracy. 
       •FASTER — Returns a fast response with a smaller sample size. 
       •HIGHER_PRECISION — Returns a more accurate response using a large sample size, 
         but this may result in the response being slower. 

If not supplied, the DEFAULT sampling level will be used.
```

You haven't stated which language you are using so your going to have to check the Library for that language and figure out how to send it.

---

Update: trying to help with code.  I haven't tested this, but my guess is you would add it to as an optional parameter.  Let me know if it doesn't work and i will see if i can get it working.

```
$optParams = array(
    'dimensions' => 'ga:dateHour,ga:hour', 
    'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=~'.$pagelink.'*', 
    'max-results' => 1, 
    'sort' => 'ga:dateHour',
    'samplingLevel' => 'HIGHER_PRECISION' );


$results_starttime = $connect->data_ga->get( 'ga:' . $signedupuser["google id"],
$startdate_analysed, 
$enddate_analysed, 
'ga:uniquePageviews', $optParams );
```

---

Update2: Make sure you downloaded the lib from GitHub [google/google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) i checked and Analytics.php from there does have code to support samplingLevel.

---

Update 3  Your getting the old version of the lib get the one from GitHub check link above.
    [google-api-php-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/)

> Status:
>
> The beta release of the next major revision (1.0.1-beta) of the
>   library is available, please migrate when possible. The newer version
>   is published on GitHub. All new development, and issue tracking, will
>   occur on Github.

Comment: Great, and where do you add it? This is my code: $results_starttime = $connect->data_ga->get(
                'ga:' . $signedupuser["google id"], 
                $startdate_analysed, 
                $enddate_analysed, 
                'ga:uniquePageviews', 
                'samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION',
                array(
                    'dimensions' => 'ga:dateHour,ga:hour',
                    'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=~'.$pagelink.'*',
                    'max-results' => 1,
                    'sort' => 'ga:dateHour'
                )
            );

Comment: Check edit i think its probably an optional Parameter.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. I added the optional parameter but I get this error message: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message '(get) unknown parameter: 'samplingLevel'

Comment: Where did you download the library from?  https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: Read the Status on the page you just linked.  Get the latest version from GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Did you by any chance exceed the [daily limits (500,000 visits)](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042498?hl=en) for sampling? If so, getting unsampled data is technically not possible.

Otherwise, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894926/unsampled-reports-automation-for-historical-data/20920858#20920858) on very similar question.

Comment: Well, the daily visits for the entire website do exceed 500,000, however, I'm only tracking individual pages within the website, where the visits are around 30,000 a day. Is that still a problem? If yes, how can I overcome this?

Comment: I regularly use the API to select out millions of rows with out sampling the data. By adding samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION the resulting json states that the data has not been sampled.  So i'm not sure what you mean about it not being possible.

Comment: DaImTo - I do as well, but if you run a query that will return more than 500,000 visits; the data will be sampled unless you are lucky enough to be using the Premium version: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042498?hl=en

Comment: As for the higher_precision attribute -- it's the same as if you drag the slider in Google Analytics web interface. It allows you to pick up data from to 500,000 visits. CoreReporting API has the same limits.