# Google Anlytics wrong visits

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

When I select a short period (1 week) I get a correct visits number, however when I select a big period like (1 month and +) I get **less than 50% of results**, this problem is started ***from 17 january***.

Comment: Sorry I forget a detail, the problem appear when I use "segments" on a big period.

Comment: If you forgot something or want to give more details, please edit your original question to add these details.

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/analytics/report-bugs/BKkf71mqRLo

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are not mentioning it in your question, I assume the "issue" is related to data-sampling that occurs if your report include data from more than 500,000 visits.

See [this page on Google Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042498?hl=en) that explains everything.

Also, [check out this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894926/unsampled-reports-automation-for-historical-data/20920858#20920858) that might help you to get **un-sampled** data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right it's data-sampling but in addition this problem is du to an other parameter that's hostname condition was based on **visit filter** I set it to **user filter** and that's work fine now. Thank you all for your responses.